# Making these image dividers horizontal

Tags: html, css, hover, divide

I'm trying to make a simple homepage with clickable images as buttons, no problem, I can do that.
But I'm stuck at this part:
I have these 4 images in dividers with on hover shadow.
Now these images are vertical under each other.
I want them horizontal next to each other.

EDIT: Got it, now I need it to center it horizontal and vertical.

Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
.imgBox 
{ 
width: 300px;
height: 600px;
display: inline-block
}

.imgBox:hover
{
display: inline-block
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; } 
</style>
    </head>
    <body background="back.jpg">
    <center>
    <div align="left">
    <div class="imgBox">
      <a target="_blank" href="IntensityBanner.png">
        <img src="IntensityBanner.png" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="600">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="imgBox">
      <a target="_blank" href="EarningsBanner.png">
        <img src="EarningsBanner.png" alt="Forest" width="300" height="600">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="imgBox">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
        <img src="DesignBanner.png" alt="Northern Lights" width="300" height="600">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="imgBox">
      <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
        <img src="SpaarGamesBanner.png" alt="Mountains" width="300" height="600">
      </a>
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Live demo: http://twanofzo.nl/test/

Comment: you can use `float:left` on `.imgBox` and please do not use `<center>` tag, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you close that first imgBox div (line 12) or it'll give you trouble.

Next, to make them display horizontally, you should just be able to either add `display: inline-block` or `float: left` to your css for `.imgBox`

Comment: Somehow still not working... Look at the updated live demo please :/ EDIT: Got it horizontal now. How do I center it horizontal and vertical?